# What happens if I add identical files on two PCs at the same time?

Tags: onedrive

I want to add my music collection to OneDrive, but my internet is pretty bad.

My OneDrive is connected to my PC and my Laptop.

If I added all the files to my PC and Laptop at the same time would it realise what I had done and sync flawlessly, or would it get itself into a complete mess?

I know it's going to take days/weeks to upload but I'd rather it didn't have to then download them too.

Comment: Since your question is about the file synchronization aspects of OneDrive, rather than the web interface, your question is more appropriate for [su].